# How to export Excel file using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, django, excel, python-2.7

I want to export Excel file using Python. I am sending csv data to my code and making Excel file. File is getting saved to particular location successful with data. But it is not showing as download, so that user got to know file is downloaded.

Some extra code is there to put validation on some columns in Excel sheet:

```
def downloadUploadExclusionDetailReport(request):
    csv_data=request.GET.get('csv_data')
    createExcel(csv_data)
    return HttpResponse(csv_data, content_type="application/text")      

def createExcel(data):
    wb=openpyxl.Workbook()
    WorkSheet=wb.create_sheet(title="report")
    data=data.split('|')
    row_count=1
    col_count=1
    for row in data:
        row=row.split(',')
        col_count=1
        for cell in row:
            WorkSheet.cell(row=row_count, column=col_count).value=cell
            col_count=col_count+1
        row_count=row_count+1
    ########Add Checked / Unchecked 
    dv1 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"checked,unchecked"', allow_blank=False)
    # Optionally set a custom error message
    dv1.error ='Your entry is not in the list'
    dv1.errorTitle = 'Invalid Entry'
    # Optionally set a custom prompt message
    dv1.prompt = 'Please select from the list'
    dv1.promptTitle = 'List Selection'
    # Add the data-validation object to the worksheet
    WorkSheet.add_data_validation(dv1)
    dv1.ranges.append('A2:A1048576')

    ########Add Exclusion Reason List
    dv2 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"limited_by_machine_size,fixed_cycle_time,moq_cannot_be_renegotiated,lt_cannot_be_renegotitaed,vendor_refused_to_be_vendor_consignment,quality_issue_dont_have_short_term_solution,fix_import_export_time,special_requirement_from_customer,new_product,others"', allow_blank=True)
    # Optionally set a custom error message
    dv2.error ='Your entry is not in the list'
    dv2.errorTitle = 'Invalid Entry'
    # Optionally set a custom prompt message
    dv2.prompt = 'Please select from the list'
    dv2.promptTitle = 'List Selection'
    # Add the data-validation object to the worksheet
    WorkSheet.add_data_validation(dv2)
    dv2.ranges.append('B2:B1048576')

    ########Add Action Category List
    dv3 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='"Max_Benefit,MTO-MTS,Vendor_Consignment,Lead_Time,Prod_Cycle_Time,MOQ,Batch_Size,Quality_Issue"', allow_blank=True)
    # Optionally set a custom error message
    dv3.error ='Your entry is not in the list'
    dv3.errorTitle = 'Invalid Entry'
    # Optionally set a custom prompt message
    dv3.prompt = 'Please select from the list'
    dv3.promptTitle = 'List Selection'
    # Add the data-validation object to the worksheet
    WorkSheet.add_data_validation(dv3)
    dv3.ranges.append('C2:C1048576')

    wb.save('C:\Python27\henkel_supply_chain\\fuploads\Template Ver 2.xlsx')
```

Comment: `'C:\Python27\henkel_supply_chain\\fuploads\Template Ver 2.xlsx'` Note, I don't think second slash before `fuploads` slash should be here`

Comment: \f is just character in python... so double slash is because one slash will get exclude... it is not a problem..